# Android. on button click, jump to an onActivity result function. IT IS POSSIBLE?

Tags: android, android-intent

i have button which have attribute `android:onClick="atnDuom"`.
There is that function

```
public void atnDuom(View view)
{
    finish();
}
```

and there is `onActivityResult` function in the same activity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            DOP = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

            user_name = data.getStringExtra("tarpVard");
            user_lastname = data.getStringExtra("tarpPav");
            institucijos_pavadinimas = data.getStringExtra("tarpInst");
            padalinio_pavadinimas = data.getStringExtra("tarpPad");
            pareigos = data.getStringExtra("tarpPar");
            mob_tel = data.getStringExtra("tarpMob");
            el_pastas = data.getStringExtra("tarpEl");

            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            DOP = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);

            if(newVard.equals("")||newPav.equals("")||newInst.equals("")||newPad.equals("")||newPar.equals("")||newMob.equals("")||newEl.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.prashome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {

                DOP.updateUserInfo(DOP, user_name, user_lastname, institucijos_pavadinimas, padalinio_pavadinimas, pareigos, mob_tel, el_pastas, newVard, newPav, newInst, newPad, newPar, newMob, newEl);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Duomenys atnaujinti", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible to execute function `onActivityResult` whithout doing anything in `atnDuom` function?
`Finish()` close activity and `onActivityResult` doesnt work :)

Comment: Could you explain better what you are trying to achieve? If you want to run the code in onActivityResult, simply extract the code into a function of its own. Then run that function in atnDuom and onActivityResult.

Comment: i can't do that because `data.getStringExtra` doesnt work in function `atnDuom` because that function doesnt have `intent data` parameter

Comment: No, but you can make the function parameter a Bundle. You would need to set the data in atnDuom. But it would work.

Comment: @Knossos can u show me a sample code?

Comment: You could accept Jorge Morales answer below, if it works for you. My  alternative won't be much different.

Answer (score 1):

You are using data from the intent, if you want to go to onActivityResult from atnDuom you will need to create a new Intent and push all the data needed

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent();
newIntent.putExtras(...);

onActivityResult(REQUEST_CODE, RESULT_OK, newIntent);
```